# How can make a regex using boost in c++?

Tags: c++, regex, boost

I need to create a regex that do the matching of 2 chars: `&` OR `|`.

The line of code is like this:

```
boost::regex EXPR( "[0-9][0-9][A-Za-z]" ) ;
```

If I type any string, I would see if the chars listed above are contained in it.
How is possible to do this?

Comment: Uuuuhm, sorry? I didn't get it.

Comment: If the string is "asd" no match.
If the string is "aaa&sss" match.
If the string is "asss|sss" match.
If the string is "asss&sfs|ssf" match.

Comment: So, in words, "some letters, followed by at least one `&` or `|`, followed by more letters or `&` or `|` ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I wouldn't write a regular expression to match the characters `&` or `|`.

I'd use `std::string::find` - http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/find/

Comment: If you're looking for either of two characters, use `find_first_of`.

Comment: @MSalters: Yeah when I was looking at `find` I thought the `char*` overload would do that, but now that I'm looking at it again, `find_first_of` makes more sense.

Answer (score 1):

Based on my interpretation of the grammar:
`[0-9A-Za-z]*[|&][0-9A-Za-z|&]*`

Answer (score 0):

This should work: `".*?\Q|\E.*"`. Note that you need to double the backslashes, so it is:

```
string yourCharacter("|"); // or "&"
string rex(".*?\\Q"+yourCharacter+"\\E.*");
```

(all characters before and after are matched by this regex)

Here is an online tool to test regular expressions: http://gskinner.com/RegExr/

Comment: Boost regex defaults to Perl syntax, which does have `\Q...\E`. But you don't need to escape characters inside a class, which is what you need here (One of two possible characters).